# Publish to npm not working even though all credentials are met

Tags: npm, npm-publish

It's my first time trying to publish a package to npm.

I have verified my email after creating an npm account.

And I also have a .npmrc file with: //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=

But for some reason I'm still getting this 403 Forbidden.

[image]